# Como fazer uma função aguardar a resposta de outra que está dentro da primeira

Tags: javascript

Tenho minha função `ABAS` que só pode dar o retorno quando a função `confirmacao` dentro dela retornar algum valor.

*Poderiam me auxiliar estou com dificuldades.*

```
ABAS[submenu]["fn_afteredit_validar_leitores"] = function(ob)
{
    var msg = "";
    if(ob.value == true)
        var msg = "Deseja incluir o leitor no nível de acesso? \r\nObs.: Será realizado o envio de lista.";
    if(ob.value == false)
        var msg = "Deseja retirar o leitor do nível de acesso? \r\nObs.: Será realizado o envio de lista.";
    confirmacao(msg, function (bt)
    {
        if(bt.answer == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });
};
```

Comment: não entendi exatamente o que deseja fazer, um `callback` talvez resolva, mas, não entendi o que deseja fazer!?

Comment: Poderia dar uma explicação mais detalhada?

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso assim

```js
    confirmacao(msg, function (err, bt) {
        if(err) {
         console.log('erro');
        } else {
          if(bt.answer == true)
            return true;
          else
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Eu acho que isso não responde, fora que sua `bt.answer` retornar um `boleano` pra que então fazer uma estrutura de decisão não está redundante?